# Paypal Sandbox Express Checkout Session Expired

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal

I've been using my seller's and buyer's Paypal sandbox accounts to purchase fakes on my  ecommerce and everything was working fine up until 1 hour ago.

Nothing has changed in my code, and I even tried to create and add new API credentials for my site, but every time I try to pay with Paypal Express I land to a "Session Expired" error page.

On someone else's machine the thing is still working.

It seems like no one on the net knows why, is it something to do with my browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, for no apparent reason, after a while you use Paypal's sandbox, you have to do the cleaning and delete all your cookies from Paypal to make it work.